# Can't bind to IsExpanded on Expander

Tags: wpf, binding, controls, expander, blacklight

Blacklight is an older set of WPF controls and styles.  The code can be found [here](http://blacklight.codeplex.com).  It contains a control called AnimatedExpander which isn't really an expander, rather it just implements HeaderedContentControl and adds an IsExpandedProperty dprop:

```
    public static readonly DependencyProperty IsExpandedProperty =
       DependencyProperty.Register("IsExpanded", typeof(bool), typeof(AnimatedExpander), new PropertyMetadata(true));

    public bool IsExpanded
    {
        get
        {
            if (this.expandToggleButton != null)
            {
                return this.expandToggleButton.IsChecked.Value;
            }

            return (bool)GetValue(IsExpandedProperty);
        }

        set
        {
            SetValue(IsExpandedProperty, value);
        }
    }
```

I need to bind to IsExpanded so that I can persist whether expanders are expanded.  I'm pretty sure I have the binding setup correctly, and that there is a problem with this custom dependency property.  If I open the view in Snoop, and set the IsExpanded=True on the expander, the binding works.  However, just clicking the expandToggleButton on the control only expands the control, it doesn't hit my binding.

```
    <controls:AnimatedExpander IsExpanded="{Binding SGGExpanderExpanded}" />

    private bool _sGGExpanderExpanded;
    public bool SGGExpanderExpanded
    {
        get { return _sGGExpanderExpanded; }
        set
        {
            if (_sGGExpanderExpanded != value)
            {
                _sGGExpanderExpanded = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("SGGExpanderExpanded");
            }
        }
    }
```

How can I bind to a value that changes when the user clicks the toggle button that is wired to expand the control?

Comment: post the full code and XAML of that control.

Comment: Thanks for the interest.  The code is available at the link, and can be tested by simply binding one of the example AnimatedExpanders to a dummy viewmodel. 

As I have the bad solution I mentioned working, I can't afford to waste a bunch of time looking for a good solution right now.  I'll try to come back on the weekend to find a pure MVVM solution.

Comment: right. I'm almost sure that the problem you're having is due to a bad implementation in that control.

Comment: Here's the control.  I shared above what looked fishy to me (details in a dprop, which I know WPF can ignore).  After more research I'm thinking some style is getting in the way.

Here are the two files:

http://blacklight.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/15166#267951

http://blacklight.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/15166#267944

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A bad solution:

I was able to make this work by attaching an event to the ToggleButton click and looking at the "sender" Content  and IsChecked values to update my viewmodel.